# WPF Canvas Fill

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I currently have a WPF windows with a Canvas is 600 x 400. Is it possible to scale or automatically zoom in so that the lines take up as much as the 600x600 as possible?

```
   <Border>
          <Canvas x:Name="cMap" Width="600" Height="400">
                 <Line X1="5" Y1="5" X2 ="10" Y2="10" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black"/>
                 <Line X1="10" Y1="10" X2 ="15" Y2="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black"/>
          </Canvas>
   </Border>
```

My intention will be to add lines programmatically via code instead of XAML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is your exact usecase, but you could probably benefit by using `ViewBox`:

```
<Border>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas x:Name="cMap" Width="15" Height="25">
            <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform />
            </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <Line X1="5" Y1="5" X2 ="10" Y2="10" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black"/>
            <Line X1="10" Y1="10" X2 ="15" Y2="25" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you!

To draw lines in code you shoud do something like this:

```
Line line = new Line();
    Thickness thickness = new Thickness(101,-11,362,250);
    line.Margin = thickness;
    line.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    line.StrokeThickness = 4;
    line.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
    line.X1 = 10;
    line.X2 = 40;
    line.Y1 = 70;
    line.Y2 = 70;
```

and don't forget to add:

```
myCanvas.Children.Add(line);
```

to put those line in some place

from: [Drawing lines in code using C# and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969503/drawing-lines-in-code-using-c-sharp-and-wpf)

To resize your canvas please [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.canvas?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Canvas is the only panel element that has no inherent layout
>   characteristics. A Canvas has default Height and Width properties of
>   zero, unless it is the child of an element that automatically sizes
>   its child elements. Child elements of a Canvas are never resized, they
>   are just positioned at their designated coordinates. This provides
>   flexibility for situations in which inherent sizing constraints or
>   alignment are not needed or wanted. For cases in which you want child
>   content to be automatically resized and aligned, it is usually best to
>   use a Grid element.

So as a solution you would make it inside a GRID or using the following code:

```
public class CanvasAutoSize : Canvas
{
protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint)
{
    base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    double width = base
        .InternalChildren
        .OfType<UIElement>()
        .Max(i => i.DesiredSize.Width + (double)i.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty));

    double height = base
        .InternalChildren
        .OfType<UIElement>()
        .Max(i => i.DesiredSize.Height + (double)i.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty));

    return new Size(width, height);
}
}
```

at your XAML:

```
 <local:CanvasAutoSize VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></local:CanvasAutoSize>
```

from: [WPF: How to make canvas auto-resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855334/wpf-how-to-make-canvas-auto-resize)