# Shape with slanted lines as background

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, background, shapes

Is possible to draw a [`Shape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes(v=VS.95).aspx) that has a background made by slanted lines?

An example with `Rectangle` (sorry for the image quality):

[image]

And if i want dashed lines or change the line properties (stroke, thickness..)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use solution from this article http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/06/creating-hatched-patterned-brush-in-wpf.html

```
<VisualBrush
  x:Key="HatchBrush"
  TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,10,10"
  ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,10,10"   
  ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
  <VisualBrush.Visual>
    <Canvas>
       <Rectangle Fill="Azure" Width="10" Height="10" />
       <Path Stroke="Purple" Data="M 0 0 l 10 10" />
    </Canvas>
  </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

Just change the parameters etc. to fit your application

Usage:

```
<Rectangle Width="80" Height="40"
    Fill="{StaticResource HatchBrush}"/>
```

Comment: @Nick Than you have to use methods FindResource("HatchBrush") of your main window (if you stored this resource in main window) or in Application. Just look into methods _FindResource_

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: [[WPF, C#: Draw a line onto existing bitmap in image control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231086/wpf-c-draw-a-line-onto-existing-bitmap-in-image-control)] or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx